# Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection: Adding services inside a scope

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I started looking into `Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection` / `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` (renamed post-beta 8) for usage in my own framework based on the MVC-paradigm.

For this I per request have 3 scoped levels in which I'm trying to use the new Microsoft DI. A shared root scope for my the entire application, a nested scope for every controller and a further nested scope for every view.

Even though this scoping works for resolving services from the root, I have no idea on how to inject services into the lower scopes. I want to be able to inject specific services for my controllers/views per request which are used during the lifetime of the request and then discarded.

The possibilities I've explored are `IServiceScopeFactory` and `CreateScope`, but that only gives me a read-only `IServiceProvider`. Other than that there's `AddScoped` but that just returns the original `ServiceCollection`.

Am still looking for a way to create the root containers, register its services for the entire application and then the ability to create a scope and register scoped only available in that scope (and its parents).

Any ideas on how to achieve this? The documentation for the Microsoft DI is scarce so far.

Comment: what did you tried till now?

Comment: Well I tried resolving IServiceScopeFactory from the root scope and then using CreateScope(), which gives me access to a scoped IServiceProvider. But that's readonly and can only resolve services. I need access to a similarly scoped IServiceCollection (or similar) so I can register services for that scope only which doesn't interfere with any other scopes outside that nested chain.

Comment: Please put the additional info in your question!

Comment: Updated my comment above to original the question

Comment: The new dependency injection model from Microsoft is intended to provide basic DI functionality. I may be wrong, but registering objects only to a specific scope may not be supported. If you really want an elaborate DI scheme, you may want to swap it out for autofac or some other more mature di container.

Comment: Was just impressed with the speed of MS DI (which I need), so was hoping there was some kind of trick doing this. Especially as it was built for MVC, so was thinking it'd work with a multi scoped hierarchy like mine. Anyway thanks. I'll see what I can figure out.